# Geojson to shapefile using Python

Tags: python, geojson, shapefile

I'm trying to convert a geojson file into a shapefile.
I'm trying this way (I'm very new to Python so it might be incorrect).

```
import urllib, geojson, gdal
url= ' http://ig3is.grid.unep.ch/istsos/wa/istsos/services/ghg/procedures/operations/geojson?epsg=4326'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = geojson.loads(response.read())

file = open ('data.geojson', 'w')
pickle.dump(data,file)
file.close()
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp "data.geojson"
```

So I'm getting the data from an url, put it in a file and when I try to convert it into a shapefile I got this error:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1
    ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp "data.geojson"
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I'm quite new I tried the solutions that I found on the web. Is there any way of making this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ogr2ogr appears to be a command line program - to use this you might want to look into something like [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
import urllib, geojson, gdal, subprocess
url= ' http://ig3is.grid.unep.ch/istsos/wa/istsos/services/ghg/procedures/operations/geojson?epsg=4326'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = geojson.loads(response.read())

with open('data.geojson', 'w') as f:
    geojson.dump(data, f)

args = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'destination_data.shp', 'data.geojson']
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

EDIT: In response to comments - yes, `pickle` is not the appropriate way to go about writing to the file in this case.

Comment: When I do this, I got another error
>> ERROR 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `data.geojson' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
To be honnest I'm not so sure about my way of getting the geojson.

file = open ('data.geojson', 'w')
pickle.dump(data,file)
file.close()

Comment: @Gus you're write - I've edited my response. This does seem to write the geojson data to the file, though I can't test the `ogr2ogr` part unfortunately.

Comment: thanks, it's working now. pickle was indeed not the right way.