# How to convert a created/converted Geojson to a shapefie using gdal/ogr2ogr in python and save it?

Tags: python, gdal

Before you review this question; yes I have checked to similar questions and different tutorials but none of them gave me a straight forward answer or something at least a little bit of understanding.

The closest I have gotten is this answer: the closest answer I have found is this:
[Geojson to shapefile using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049679/geojson-to-shapefile-using-python)

I have written a program to request a JSON from an API and convert to the GeoJSON standard.

However I am trying to find a method (like what you have in QGIS processing Convert Format) to convert this created geojson feature collection to a shapefile format.

There is a bit of a problem with this GeoJSON, while most of the time around 99% of the objects the features are Polygons in 1% of the case certain data is a geometry collection.

This is why I used QGIS GDAL convert format (ogr2ogr to get in to the format I wanted and to set those geometry collections back to Polygon data. Now this GDAL/OGR2OGR is something I want to integrate into my script with a convertion to a shapefile format.

So how do I this? Can someone please give me an example and some understandable code to use?

The best I have come up with is this:

```
def geojson_convertion(geojson_data_path):
    data = geojson.loads(geojson_data_path.read())
    with open('data.geojson', 'w') as f:
        geojson.dump(data, f)
    args = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'data-output.shp', 'data.geojson']
    subprocess.Popen(args)
```

**But how to export this is a bit unclear.**